# I want to show how many of the alumni attended the social event

Tags: sql, oracle

I want an output to show how many alumni attended the event 
I got Event Table

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT 
(EVENTID INTEGER CONSTRAINT EVENT_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY,
EDATEANDTIME VARCHAR2(20),
EVENUE VARCHAR2(30),
EAUDIENCE VARCHAR2(30),
EATTENDED VARCHAR2(30),
EVENT_ALUMNI INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT EVENT_ALUMNI_FK FOREIGN KEY (EVENT_ALUMNI) REFERENCES
ALUMNI(ALUMNIID));
```

Here is what I inserted in Event

```
INSERT INTO EVENT VALUES(25993, 'Jan 14, 2015', 'Concorde Hall', 'Tobias, Tucker, Felix, Nicole, Desiree, Taylor, Frant, Ifeoma, Forrest, Stewart, Cole, Arthur, Thomas, Bo, Lucian', 
'Tobias, Tucker, Felix, Nicole, Desiree, Taylor, Frant, Ifeoma, Forrest, Stewart, Cole, Arthur, Thomas, Bo',17337);


INSERT INTO EVENT VALUES(23823, 'July 18 2015', 'Rochester Hotel', 'Joan, Thalia, Haleeda', 'Joan, Haleeda'
    ,19927);
```

And I have a View Statement to view how many attended

```
CREATE VIEW VIEWH AS SELECT ETYPE, EDATEANDTIME, COUNT (*) EATTENDED FROM EVENT 
WHERE EDATEANDTIME LIKE '%2015%' AND ETYPE = 'Social'
GROUP BY ETYPE, EDATEANDTIME, EATTENDED;
```

Here is where I got problem. When i run the query, the output is I got only one who attended the event instead of like 10 or 15

[image]

I want to know where i went wrong.

Comment: show some sample data in your table which indicates it has more than two social events for year 2015

Comment: You provide incorrect test data. Your sql doesn't insert data because value too long(113 charachters are inserted in column limited to 30). Data format 'Jan 14, 2015' may be not consistent with data format other users.

Comment: This doesn't seem like homework, so it must be some sort of real-life application. Do you just need help with this query, or would you like more help, like with better database structure? For example, datetimes should never be stored as strings. You shouldn't have details of an event (like venue) and one-to-many relationships (who attended) in the same table. Etc.

Comment: @rqula what information does the column `EATTENDED` consists of?

Answer (score 0):

There are several potential problems with your setup, I mentioned a couple in a Comment to your question.

Regarding the count specifically: your first problem is you have EATTENDED in the GROUP BY clause. Why? This almost surely means that each group is exactly one row.

Then your next problem is counting tokens out of a comma-separated string. One way is using `regexp_count()` as TheGameiswar has shown. (err... his/her solution has disappeared? anyway, I was saying...)

Another is to use `length()` and `translate()`:

```
select ...   , 1 + length(EATTENDED) - length(translate(EATTENDED, ',', '') as ATT_CNT  ...
```

A couple of notes about this:

The length difference, just like `regexp_count()`, counts commas in the string. You add one to count tokens (you don't care how many commas there are, you care how many names are separated by commas). `translate()` works faster than `regexp_count()` (all `regexp` functions are very powerful, but slower, so they should be used only when they are really needed, IF performance is important); `length` doesn't add much overhead since in Oracle the length of VARCHAR2 is always calculated and stored as part of the internal representation of a string.

I gave a different alias to the resulting column; in your original query you use the same name, EATTENDED, for a column in your base table and as an alias for this numeric column in your view. You can do it, it's legal, but it is almost certain to cause problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `COUNT` gives number of "rows" in the result and not number of "values in column".

To give you a simple example

example1_table:

```
 col1
 --------
 a
 b
 c

SELECT COUNT(col1) FROM example1_table; // The result is 3, as there are three rows
```

example2_table:

```
 col1  
 --------
 a,b,c

SELECT COUNT(col1) FROM example1_table; // The result is 1, as there is only one row (it is not about number of values in it)
```

Note:

As stated by @mathguy you could have used a better Database structure.
Instead of using only one table `EVENT` create two tables let they be: `table1` `table2` so you could avoid redundancy.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 
(EVENTID INTEGER CONSTRAINT EVENT_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY,
EDATEANDTIME VARCHAR2(20),
EVENUE VARCHAR2(30),
EVENT_ALUMNI INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT tab1_FK FOREIGN KEY (EVENT_ALUMNI) REFERENCES
ALUMNI(ALUMNIID));

CREATE TABLE table2
(
EAUDIENCE VARCHAR2(30),
EATTENDED VARCHAR2(30),
tab2ID INTEGER
CONSTRAINT tab2_FK FOREIGN KEY (tab2ID) REFERENCES
tab1(EVENT_ALUMNI));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make any changes in your table, assuming there is always a comma present between two attendees names you could try:

```
CREATE VIEW VIEWH AS SELECT ETYPE, EDATEANDTIME, regexp_count(EATTENDED,',')+1 FROM EVENT WHERE EDATEANDTIME LIKE '%2015%' AND ETYPE = 'Social' GROUP BY ETYPE, EDATEANDTIME;
```